# Mule & Java - Byte[] to File

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, base64, mule

I get a `JSON` with two nodes:

1. The **file name** with the **extension** - `String`.
2. The **content** - **Encoded** with Base64 - `String`.

With that data I want to **put an object** in my `Amazon S3` but it requires a `File` type parameter.

I use this to  transform to `byte[]` too:

```
byte[] arrayDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(node2JSON);
```

I want to transform the **byte[ ] to File** in a java class Java and then put it to Amazon S3.

How can I do that without using files from a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AmazonS3#putObject(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input,ObjectMetadata metadata)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata)) method to upload the data without writing a file to the filesystem.
Specify the length of the file in the metadata and use a ByteArrayInputStream to convert your byte array to an input stream.

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setContentLength(data.length);
amazonS3.putObject(bucketName, filename, new ByteArrayInputStream(data), objectMetadata);
```

Comment: Thanks that was that I needed !

Answer (score 0):

You could use the S3 Connector in Mule.

Use set-payload with #[org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(node2JSON)]